# Embedding images in an e-mail with Microsoft365R

Tags: r, microsoft365r

I'm trying to send an email with the Microsoft365R package.
There's an embedded image I need in it. I've tried two ways:

```
library(Microsoft365R)

emails <- c("myemail@example.com")

for(i in emails){
my_outlook <- get_business_outlook()
my_email <- my_outlook$create_email()$
  set_body("<img src=`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iagocnunes/test/main/002.png` alt=`image`>", content_type="html")$
  set_subject("Test")$
  set_recipients(to = i)$
  send()
}
```

And:

```
for(i in emails){
  my_outlook <- get_business_outlook()
  my_email <- my_outlook$create_email()$
    set_body("<b>test testing", content_type="html")$
    add_image("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iagocnunes/test/main/002.png")$
    set_subject("Test")$
    set_recipients(to = i)$
    send()
}
```

In both the image fails to embed. Why is this happening and how can I get it right?

Comment: Can you try the first example again, but replace the 4 backticks with `'` (single quotes).

Comment: @stevec Thank you, it worked! Such a minor detail

Comment: That's great. I'll make it into an answer, along with another tip I was thinking of (which doesn't apply in your case but may help others if they have a similar problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things could cause an image not to render as expected.

In this case, the backtick characters should be replaced with `'` single quotes and it should work. E.g. this should work

```
library(Microsoft365R)

emails <- c("myemail@example.com")

for(i in emails){
my_outlook <- get_business_outlook()
my_email <- my_outlook$create_email()$
  set_body("<img src='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iagocnunes/test/main/002.png' alt='image'>", content_type="html")$
  set_subject("Test")$
  set_recipients(to = i)$
  send()
}
```

A second thing that can cause images not to render as expected is if the image's mimetype isn't what it appears to be. Basically, we could reasonably assume that if a file has the extension `.png`, that its mimetype is also png. However, sometimes someone will have an unsupported image type, they'll rename it (giving it a different extension), but it won't change it's mimetype and so it won't render (this happened to me once with the `webp` file type). I checked your image's mimetype [here](https://www.htmlstrip.com/mime-file-type-checker) and confirm it's mimetype is `image/png`, which is a supported type.

One last thing that could cause an image not to render (you already have this) is if the `content_type="html"` argument is missing in `set_body()` (see [microsoft365R manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Microsoft365R/Microsoft365R.pdf#page=11)):

> The object argument should be a filename, and the message content type will be set to "html"